# angular delete component from history on toggle

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular I have parents as chapters and children as lectures, once the user clicked on a chapter, toggle will show this chapter's lectures and hide the other chapters' lectures.
I've named lectures class with the chapterId e.g. list-lectures203 where 203 is the id of these lectures' chapter and so on
I've to do this for Dragula service as createGroup,so far it works for the first showing
now if I clicked back on any chapter it will says that the class name already exist

Group named: "lectures-list203" already exists.

I think this because the Html already rendered before and still there so how can I solve this issue?

[image]

```
this.dragulaService.createGroup(`lectures-list${this.chapter.id}`, {
  moves: function (el, container, handle) {
    return !handle.classList.contains('edit-mode');
  }
});

<ul [ngClass]="canDrag?'':'edit-mode'" class="list-group" [(dragulaModel)]="courseLecturesForm.value.lectures"  dragula="lectures-list{{this.chapter.id}}" id="lectures-list{{this.chapter.id}}">

  <li [ngClass]="canDrag?'':'edit-mode'" class="list-group-item draggable array-card-header" formArrayName="lectures"
    *ngFor="let lecture of  courseLecturesForm.get('lectures')['controls']; let i = index;">
   </li>
   </ul>


toggle(item, i) {
  item.shown = !item.shown;
   this.current = i;
 }
```

Comment: I'm using toggle to hide old lectures menu once I click on another chapter to open another lectures menu!! did you got what I meant? the problem here once i open one it will be loaded as html with the class name which is assigned to the chapter id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to destory drag service in ngOnDestroy

```
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.dragulaService.destroy(`lectures-list${this.chapter.sort_order}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You will find answer below

```js
//ts file

selectedMenu='';
toggle(id){
this.selectedMenu=id;
}
```

```html
<!-- html file -->
  <ul >

    <li *ngFor="let lecture of  courseLecturesForm.get('lectures')['controls']; let i = index;" (click)="toggle(chapterid)"  >

      <child-component [ngClass]="{selected:selectedMenu==chapterid}"></child-component>

        <!--or -->

        <ul [ngClass]="{selected:selectedMenu==chapterid}"></ul>

    </li>

  </ul>
```

According to my knowledge this is what you are looking for. Let me know any changes you need.